# Regex: why ; is not kept at the end

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm still sucking at regex. I tried in chrome dev tools:

```
  regex = /\s|[(\;)]/;
  test = "test test-test-test test;"
  test.split(regex);
```

It didn't keep ";"

```
["test", "test-test-test", "test", ""]
```

whereas I wanted to get

```
["test", "test-test-test", "test", ";"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider splitting on the following slightly updated regex:

```
\s|(?=;)
```

This splits on a whitespace character *or* on a zero-width positive lookahead which asserts semicolon.  The lookahead does not consume anything.

```js
test = "test test-test-test test;"
var out = test.split(/\s|(?=;)/);
console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `[(\;)]` will match either a `(`, a `;`, or a `)`. If you wanted that to be a capture group, move it *outside* the character set, and filter out empty/undefined results to account for when the capture group is not matched. Since all you want to match is `;`, there's no need for a character set anymore either:

```js
regex = /\s|(;)/;
test = "test test-test-test test;"
console.log(test.split(regex).filter(Boolean));
```

Comment: Note: It is character _class_, not set, AFAIK.